# Cosmic strings, monopoles and textures

Tags: cosmology, topology

I am a beginner in topology and I want some help in visualizing the following statements:
"Strings arise when manifold contains non-contractible loops"
"Monopoles arise when manifold contains non-contractible 2-spheres"
"Textures arise when manifold contains non-contractible 3-spheres"

Can someone help me to understand what the word "non-contractible" means in this context?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Contractible.html

Comment: Some help in the Wikipedia article [Magnetic monopole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole).